# Como validar nome da porta Serial USB

Tags: c#, winforms, porta-serial

Gente, eu estou fazendo a homologação de uma balança em c#, consigo realizar a comunicação via código tudo certinho, porem ao realizar a conexão, eu preciso especificar o nome da porta,tenho outros dispositivos conectados e o nome da porta varia de maquina para maquina.

**Alguém pode me ajudar a validar a porta onde a balança esta conectada?**

Por enquanto deixei o nome estático como COM15, mas o nome da porta pode mudar.

Eu estou abrindo uma conexão assim, funciona, mas o nome não pode ser estatico.

```
//Definindo a porta
 SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM15", 2400, Parity.None, 8,StopBits.One);
//Abrindo a porta
 port.Open();
```

Tentei pegar os nomes de todas as portas conectadas, porem não sei distinguir qual é a porta da balança.

```
//Pegando o nomes das portas conectadas
 string[] Portas = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

**Tem alguma forma de saber se a porta conectada é da balança?**

**Obs:** utilizo um cabo de conversor serial para USB.

Comment: Não seria o caso de listar as portas e tentar verificar que dispositivo está conectado na mesma?

Comment: Acho que não tem muito o que fazer neste caso, no geral deve ficar como configuração para o usuário, a menos que você tente conectar porta por porta e testar enviar algum comando para ver se é o dispositivo correto

Comment: E se ao invés de mapear as porta, utilizar os identificades VID e PID do dispositivo USB?

Comment: Oii gente, obrigada pela ajuda. Eu consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma: criei um parâmetro na configuração do sistema, ou seja toda vez que eu for instalar o sistema ele define o nome correto da porta

Comment: Fiz isso usando um combobox, ai o usuário só precisa selecionar a porta uma vez

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente as balanças tem comunicação bidirecional, você manda um comando e ela te responde, pode ser uma solicitação de peso, um ping, qq coisa do tipo, então você deve verificar em todas as portas COM ativas, dessa forma você consegue identificar, mas o ideal é fazer isso sempre que for abrir o sistema e não apenas na instalação, pois a porta serial pode mudar de COM se o usuário trocar a porta USB, depois de alguma atualização do windows ou coisas do tipo.